# How to deallocate objects in NSMutableArray with ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

My original project was leaking so I searched for the leak. When I found it I created a simple new project.
The project uses ARC and the only code I added is the following.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    int elements = 10000000;
    //memory usage 5,2 MB

    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:elements];
    //memory usage 81,7 MB

    for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
        [array addObject:[NSObject new]];
    }
    //memory usage 234,3 MB

    [array removeAllObjects];
    //memory usage 234,3 MB

    array = nil;
    //memory usage 159,5 MB
}
```

After calling [array removeAllObjects] all NSObjects in the array should be deallocated and the memory usage should be 81,7 MB again.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Be sure to read the docs on @autoreleasepool as well for more details: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

Comment: what if you skip the `[array removeAllObjects]`?

Comment: What are you using to determine memory usage?

Comment: ARC does not and should not care about retain-release semantics that may or may not stick around.  That an autoreleasepool directive may autorelease the objects within is an implementation detail.  At most, they are suggestions to the compiler, and should not be regarded as invariants.

Comment: @David the debugger and activity monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've been bitten by the dreaded *autorelease pool*. Essentially to make MRC (manual reference counting) manageable by people instead of releasing an object immediately it can be handed to the autorelease pool (an instance of `NSAutoreleasePool`, it's documentation gives more details) which will retain the object until the pool is later *drained*. ARC (automatic reference counting) could be designed so the autorelease machinery is not needed, but to maintain compatibility with MRC is remains.

The pool automatically drained at the end of a run loop cycle - i.e. when the application has finished processing an event. However if an application creates a lot of temporary objects and  then discards them is some localised part of the program then a using a local autorelease pool can drastically reduce the maximum memory use. It is not that such temporary objects will not be release, just that they will live far longer than needed. A local pool can be create with the `@autoreleasepool { ... }` construct.

You can see the effect in your example by wrapping the whole of the body of `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
   @autoreleasepool
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

and stepping through with the debugger.

In your real code you need to work back from the point which is producing lots of temporary objects to locate a suitable point to add an autorelease pool.

HTH.

**Addendum**

It is not the objects in your array that are not getting released when you think they should , you can test this by using a simple class which counts initialisations and deallocations, e.g.:

@interface TestObject : NSObject

```
+ (void) showCounts;

@end

@implementation TestObject

static uint64_t initCount = 0, deallocCount = 0;

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) initCount++;
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    deallocCount++;
}

+ (void) showCounts
{
    NSLog(@"init: %llu | dealloc: %llu", initCount, deallocCount);
    initCount = deallocCount = 0;
}
@end
```

Use this instead of `NSObject` and call `showCounts` after you are done with your test - try with/without autorelease, etc.

Your memory is always getting released, it is just the time at which it is release that is the issue. Some objects end up in an autorelease pool, either the default one which is emptied once per event, or a local one.

Unless you create a lot of temporary objects in response to a single event you normally won't see an issue. Consider whether you are chasing a real issue for your application here. If you are among the things to try to alleviate the problem are:

- Avoid uses of convenience constructors of the form `<name>WithX...` which are shorthands for `[[[C alloc] initWithX...] autorelease]`. On many, but not all, occasions the compiler can remove such objects from the autorelease pool just after the convenience constructor returns (and your case appears to be one in which is can fail). The better route is to use `alloc`/`init`, `new` (shorthand for `alloc`/`init`) or, if provided, `newWithX...` (shorthand for `alloc`/`initWithX...`). Try these options with your example and see the differences in when (not if) the memory is released.
- Well placed `@autoreleasepool` blocks.

HTH

Comment: I added this autoreleasepool block but after leaving this block the NSObjects are still in memory.

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling with ARC?

Comment: Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting Yes

Comment: @user3573448 - I ran your exact code wrapped in an auto release block as suggested and the memory is freed. What exact code are you running?

Comment: @CRD Cocoa Application and the code in my question that's all

Comment: @user3573448 - What compiler & OS X version are you using? How are you determining memory use?

Comment: @CRD LLVM 5.0, 10.9.1, debugger and activity monitor; with autoreleaseblock and cleaning the project in the first run it works but only in the first

Comment: @user3573448 - Your `NSObject`s will always be released, it is just a question of exactly when and whether that is an issue or not. Added an addendum with more details.

Comment: @CRD autoreleasepool surrounds all of my code. with arrayWithCap the array is deallocated at the end of autoreleaseblock, with alloc initWithCap after assigning to nil. this works every time. your showCounts is also right every time but only in the first run I cleaned the project memory seems to be freed e.g. in the second run after 5 minutes the usage is still at 159,5MB. at this time the default pool should be released, does it mean at the second run the objects are in another autorelease?

Comment: @user3573448 - For exactly the same single-threaded deterministic program with exactly the same inputs memory use should not vary between runs. Either how you are determining memory use is unreliable or something else is going on. It might be better if you open a new question asking why your memory use appears different between runs, giving details of how you measure etc. (SO is now hinting this comment thread is getting too long...)

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:elements];
```

you are creating autoreleased object ([autorelease pool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html)).

> Many programs create temporary objects that are autoreleased. These
>   objects add to the program’s memory footprint until the end of the
>   block. In many situations, allowing temporary objects to accumulate
>   until the end of the current event-loop iteration does not result in
>   excessive overhead; in some situations, however, you may create a
>   large number of temporary objects that add substantially to memory
>   footprint and that you want to dispose of more quickly. In these
>   latter cases, you can create your own autorelease pool block. At the
>   end of the block, the temporary objects are released, which typically
>   results in their deallocation thereby reducing the program’s memory
>   footprint

Wrap with `@autoreleasepool {}` method `[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:elements]`:

```
NSMutableArray *array;
@autoreleasepool {
    array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:elements];
    // [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:] creates object with retainCount == 1
    // and pushes it to autorelease pool

    // array = some_object; usually (and in this case also) is transformed by ARC to 
    // [array release]; [some_object retain]; array = some_object;

    // so here array will have retainCount == 2 and 1 reference in autorelease pool

} // here autorelease pool will call `release` for its objects.
// here array will have retainCount == 1
```

or change it to

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:elements];
```

Comment: `[NSObject new]` and `[ [ NSObject alloc ] init ]` are the same, no?

Comment: `new` does not return an autoreleased object but one the caller owns

Comment: I tried both and both in one. The result is the same.

Comment: According to your memory usage stats it seems that `NSObject`s are not deallocated. But in fact the only one place where autoreleased object is used - `NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:elements];` Just wrap it with `@autoreleasepool` or change to `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:elements];`. I have run this code on my Mac and now memory is successfully deallocated at the end of the method. I have updated the answer, please check.

Comment: @nielsbot yes, new and alloc/init are synonyms (new calls alloc/init)  alloc/init (or new) returns an object the caller owns.  arrayWithCapacity returns an autoreleased object.  By changing from arrayWithCapacity to alloc/init you allow the implicit ARC release on assigning nil to release the memory allocated.

Comment: @Avt if the NSMutableArray *array is not inside autorelease block this block can not dellocate the array so it has no effect on the array right?

Comment: As Avt has the @autoreleasepool should work (it does in my tests) as the autorelease pool will allow the arrayWithCapacity autorelease to occur, having the array declaration outside of the block means that reference will still be in force and the memory not released.  However when array=nil is executed, and that release happens, the memory will be fully released.  It's a little different than one would expect, which is to just bracket the entire usage of array in an autoreleasepool (in which case you don't even need to assign nil to it), but it does work.

Comment: @user3573448 autorelease block not "deallocates" objects, it calls `release` method for them. So if object has retainCount > 1 it will not be deallocated. I have added detailed calculations to the code to show what retainCount values will have array object at every moment.

Comment: @Avt thanks, like you said "it seems that NSObjects are not dealocated" the array is deallocated; 76,5MB more when array is inited and 74,8MB less when assigned to nil; the NSObjects are still there

Comment: @avt - The compiler often *removes* objects from the autorelease pool (see `retainAutoreleasedReturnValue`) under ARC, so your explanation & solution is not general.